JavaFX what to make in Properties object?
I’m an old-school Java programmer—I’ve been using Java since its initial release. The last time I needed to make a UI in the Java world was with SWT for an Eclipse rich client, which is not something I want to do again. This background lets you know that I understand GUIs, Listeners, Observable properties, etc.
Currently, I'm trying to create a TableView to render reconciled expenses. I'm writing an app to match expenses with their corresponding credit card transactions.
I have a class (skipping the constructor and member variables):
public class ReconciledExpense {
    public String getStore() {
        return transactionData.getStore();
    }

    public BankName getBankName() {
        return transactionData.getBankName();
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return transactionData.getDate();
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return expenseData.getAmount();
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return expenseData.getCategory();
    }
}

The data is read-only, and ReconciledExpenses are kept in an ArrayList.
I see the value in changing the ArrayList to ObservableArray, so it would be aware of new reconciled expenses.
However, I'm struggling with how to turn methods like getStore into a StringProperty.
Do I:
Create a wrapper class, ReconciledExpenseWrapper, to wrap a ReconciledExpense?
Change my underlying data model from String/BigDecimal/etc. to StringProperty/ObjectProperty?
If I take the latter approach, am I promising to return the same StringProperty/ObjectProperty every time? Since the data is readonly, I'm not convinced it matters a great deal.
I don’t love the latter approach because UI decisions can start to affect my lower layers, which I try to avoid where possible. Especially since I'm not entirely sold on JavaFX yet.

You mean ObservableList, not ObservableArray, I think.

As your data is read only, it may make sense to use a record.

@jewelsea I understand, in this case there is more going on than a record allows for. These are in fact good old fashioned Objects in the OO sense of the world.

It can make sense to use a MVVM style, where, for some objects, view model objects are separate from model objects.  As the View Model is closely associated with the View, there is no issue in having it include JavaFX properties and binding.  Sometimes there is a need for a feedback notification mechanism from the model to the view model as in this diagram, so the additional architecture can just shift stuff around rather than solving problems.

Other fun things are possible. If you have, e.g., a server side API with Java Bean representations of the data, and a JavaFX client side application with a view model with data representations of the same data that follow the JavaFX properties pattern, then the JSON serialization of both representations will be the same. Jackson databinding will communicate between the two using default settings, so your server-side API can stream JSON out from the Java Beans and your FX client can consume it directly into the (JavaFX) view model entities. (GSON does not work for this, unfortunately.)

If the properties are read-only, there is no benefit to wrapping them in Property instances (if they can't change, there's little value in adding a listener to them). Just keep the class as-is, and wrap the properties at the last possible moment: in the cell value factory for the table column. I.e. you can have something like
storeColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getStore())
);

You can even use this approach with records, e.g.:
public record Transaction(String store, BankName bankName){}

public record ReconciledExpense(Transaction transactionData, LocalDate date, BigDecimal amount, String category) {
    public String getStore() {
        return transactionData.store();
    }
    public BankName getBankName() {
        return transactionDate.bankName();
    }
}

and then the cell value factory above works as before.
For completeness, since you asked

If I take the latter approach, am I promising to return the same StringProperty/ObjectProperty every time?

Generally speaking, if you were to write a class whose properties were implemented with JavaFX properties, then yes, you should return the same property instance every time. The pattern I use is
public class ReconciledExpense {

    private final StringProperty store = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public ReconciledExpense() {
        setStore(transactionData.getStore());
    }

    public StringProperty storeProperty() {
        return store;
    }

    public final String getStore() {
        return storeProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setStore(String store) {
        storeProeprty().set(store);
    }

}

The basic contract is that getStore() and storeProperty().get() should return the same value (assuming setStore() is not called in between, etc. etc.). The pattern above allows for subclassing and overriding storeProperty() while enforcing that contract, but you'll see a lot of code where all three property accessor methods are final, which is fine too.
There are also patterns for read-only properties (which I generally use for properties whose values depend on other properties).
But again, to emphasize, it sounds like in your use case you should just stick with the Java Bean style and just wrap the value in a property when you set up the table column's cell value factory.

Thanks that is basically what I was looking for. I appreciate your example class as well, it all makes sense. My reluctance to use Embed properties everywhere is that codebase bloats for the a problem I don't need solved. A ReconciledExpense etc are immutable. Any I appreciate the rapid answer.
